# How to add header to section in recyclerview android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use Recyclerview to make my own gallery
It's work but not completly like I want.

there is the result of my code:

[image: picture withou headers]

I would like to produce this result:

[image: picture with headers]

there is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private String[] list ;
    private RecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            },200);
            return;
        }

        list = new String[new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "folderName").list().length];
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        getPictureList();
    }

    private void getPictureList() {
        File[] files = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "folderName").listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            list[i] = files[i].getAbsolutePath();
        }
        Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(list));
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(list));

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

now there is my Recyclerview adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private String[] list;
    public RecyclerAdapter(String[] list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_view_layout, viewGroup, false);
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(imageView);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        Bitmap ThumbImage = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(list[i]), 150, 150);
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(ThumbImage);
        viewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PreviewPicture.class);
                intent.putExtra("fileName", list[i]);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.length;
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imageView;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull ImageView itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

And my image_view_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ImageView>
```

The result is m'y first picture.

NOTE:

My picture names are picture_TIMESTAMP.jpg

and for each date I would like to make section like real gallery in phone

thanks!

Comment: You need to create a separate adapter for header on each section, check this for more information https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

Comment: I will try but I already see this solution I'm not sure about the result thanks ! @Ladd.c

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/e81e126227f8a4bb339c

Answer (score 0):

Create another recyclerview with a new adapter and layout that contains the actual recyclerview and a textfield on top of it(your main activity turns into your new recyclerView containing the actual one), then you'll need to sort your images by date and put the right list on each sub-recyclerView